# Blazor MainLayout and injected state in Hosted WASM

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I have a hosted WASM app, so I have a Blazor Server project serving a Blazor WASM client.

For the client side, I'm setting an AppState object in Program.cs like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppState>();
```

In the server code, in my _Host.cshtml.cs I'm creating an AppState object, and passing it to the WASM client.

```
ProvidedAppState = new AppState{ ... }
```

In the client App.razer file I'm getting that and setting the scoped AppState like this:

```
@inject AppState AppState
@if (!isLoading)
{
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            ...
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
}
@code {
    bool isLoading = true;
    [Parameter]
    public AppState ProvidedAppState{ get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AppState = ProvidedAppState; // Always seems to work
        ...
        isLoading = false;
    }
```

On the initial startup of the client... there is no AppState. My LoginForm.razor calls Authentication.cs LoginAsync method which sets the injected AppState:

```
public Authentication(HttpClient client,
    AppState appState,
    IUserService userService)
{
    _client = client;
    _appState = appState;
    _userService = userService;
}

public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string? username, string? password)
{
    ...
    var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("auth/login", new LoginUserInfo { Username = username, Password = password });
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ExternalUserDto? userData;
        (var statusCode, userData) = await _userService.GetUserData(username);
        if (userData != null)
        {
            _appState.IsAuthenticated = true;
            _appState.ExternalUserData = userData;
        }
```

After login, the UI hits MainLayout.razor which does see the AppState then loads my content:

```
@inject AppState AppState
@inject IUserService UserService
...
@if (isLoading)
{
    <LoadingHandler IsVisible="@isLoading" LoadingMessage="Loading Page..." />
}
else
{
    @if (AppState.IsAuthenticated) // After login, this works
    {
        <div class="main" style="padding-bottom: 100px">
            <div class="content px-4">
                @Body
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

@code {
    bool isLoading = false;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        // AppState is an empty object, not null, on page refresh
        var username = AppState.ExternalUserData.Email;
        isLoading = false;
    }
```

If I refresh the page tho, _Host.cshtml.cs loads the AppState correctly, App.razor sees the AppState, but MainLayout.razor sees an empty AppState. Following the call stack, I see App.razor OnInitializedAsync complete, THEN MainLayout.razor's OnInitializedAsync start, but the AppState is empty.

I'm assuming 1 of 2 things. 1) MainLayout.razor is using a state previous to App.razor, even tho it seems to be running after, which would mean a threading issue. 2) AppState is somehow disposed before MainLayout.razor calls for it.

How could I diagnose this?